# How do I calibrate RGB Image with Depth Image taken using Kinect (X-box)?

Tags: image, kinect, rgb, depth, calibration

I need to map Depth Image that I got from Kinect (X-box) to RGB image (taken from kinect). The problem is that the depth image size is different from that of the RGB image. And I want to calibrate these images and get their pixels. How do I calibrate them? I want the exact same size for both of the images. And the object in the depth image should map on the object in the rgb image.

Comment: Have you looked at the Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit examples, which offer multiple examples of working with color and depth data - both individually and together?

Comment: Yes I did, but I couldn't find anything. Secondly, my kinect is the x-box kinect so wouldn't the method be different of kinect for windows?

Comment: No, they are exactly the same.  The "Depth with Color" and "Green Screen" examples demonstrate how to use both streams.  There are also built in functions to handle mapping: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinectsensor.mapdepthframetocolorframe.aspx